# Get total memory size on sun os through kstat

Tags: solaris, memory

I have sun os there Following commands are not available

```
prtconf
prtdiag
psrinfo
```

The only command which is working is `kstat`.

Can any one please help me on finding the total memory size using only `kstat` command on this machine?

Comment: Why wouldn't you have access to `prtconf`, `prtdiag`, or `psrinfo`?  I'm tempted to post the `psrinfo` **PERL script**....

Answer (score 2):

The `physmem` value from the `system_pages` statistics will give you the number of pages the OS sees. You need to multiply this number by the default page size which can be 4K or 8K depending on your architecture:

```
$ kstat -n system_pages -p -s physmem |
    nawk -v pagesize=$(pagesize) '{print $2*pagesize/1024/1024 "MB"}'
4017.64MB
```

Note that this might not match the real size of RAM installed as a portion of it might already be grabbed by the hardware before the OS boots.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have either `swap` or `mdb`?

Maybe `kstat :::physmem`, which should give you the number of pages.  (8K on SPARC, 4K on x86 in most situations)

Comment: Except page size on SPARC is 8K

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to use:

```
echo "::memstat" |mdb -k
```

Answer (score 0):

There's also `lgrpinfo` ([man page](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E36784_01/html/E36870/lgrpinfo-1.html)):

> **Description**
>
> `lgrpinfo` prints information about the locality group (`lgroup`)
>   hierarchy and its contents.
>
> An `lgroup` represents the set of CPU and memory-like hardware devices
>   that are at most some distance (latency) apart from each other. All
>   `lgroups` in the system are identified by a unique integer called an
>   `lgroup` ID.
>
> `lgroups` are organized into a hierarchy to facilitate finding the
>   nearest resources. Leaf `lgroups` each contain a set of resources that
>   are closest (local) to each other. Each parent `lgroup` in the
>   hierarchy contains the resources of its child `lgroups` plus their
>   next nearest resources. Finally, the root `lgroup` contains all the
>   resources in the domain within the largest latency.
>
> A Uniform Memory Access (UMA) machine is simply represented by the
>   root `lgroup`. A Non Uniform Memory Access (NUMA) machine is
>   represented by a hierarchy of `lgroups` to show the corresponding
>   levels of locality. For example, a NUMA machine with two latencies
>   (local and remote) has an `lgroup` hierarchy consisting of two levels
>   with its leaves and the root.
>
> ...

On an Intel x86 machine (uniform memory access), `lgrpinfo` without any arguments will produce output similar to

```
bash-4.1$ lgrpinfo
lgroup 0 (root):
    Children: none
    CPUs: 0-15
    Memory: installed 48G, allocated 15G, free 33G
    Lgroup resources: 0 (CPU); 0 (memory)
    Load: 0.0445
    Latency: 0
```